# charindex wrong result

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, query-performance

Charindex returns no record if only one letter is provided.
If parameter matches the whole word it shows the record.
Why???

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[filter_opombe] 
@opombe_par nchar(256)
AS
BEGIN    
    SELECT Id_opombe
    FROM opombe
    WHERE (CHARINDEX(@opomba_par, opomba,0) > 0)
END
```

Thanks for all your replies in advance.

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. There are a few problems with your question preventing answers. Please show all the code and table definitions and sample data. Please do the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) read through the [help section](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works. especially how to [ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will attract more answers and useful feedback.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll try to keep that in mind the very next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare it as (n)varchar(x) if you need a variable length string:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[filter_opombe] 
(   
@opombe_par nvarchar(256)
)
AS
BEGIN
(
SELECT        Id_opombe
FROM            opombe
WHERE        (CHARINDEX(@opomba_par, opomba,0) > 0)
)
END
```

With a (n)char data type, shorter string will be stuffed with white space at the end: 'x' with data type nchar(5), becomes `'x    '`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quickest reply.

And thanks for the idea. I wasn't going in that direction. But now it's all clear. It wasn't as much a type but rather to trim the parameter was the solution:

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[filter_opombe] 
(   
@opombe_par nchar(256)
)
AS
BEGIN
(
SELECT        Id_opombe
FROM            opombe
WHERE        (CHARINDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(@opomba_par)), opomba,0) > 0)
)
END
```

Solved. It seems to work now.

EDIT:

Sorry all of you guys. I went throgh it again and Juliens answer works like a charm.

Comment: And LTRIM is not needed.

Comment: If this is the answer, shouldn't you select this one instead?

Comment: But why use `nchar` and be forced to trim the value to get the correct results? Why not use `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 0):

To improve this thread even further, I'll post the solution with CHARINDEX for filtering multiple columns by single letters or strings regardless nulls, empty spaces. This may probably help anyone searching for this kind of a solution.

After you've declared all those parameters (inside the parameter section of your function) gained from filter textboxes or textboxes anywhere on your form:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[filter m_t_z_o]
(   
    @m_par nvarchar(30),
    @t_par nvarchar(30),
    @z_par nvarchar(30),
    @o_par nvarchar (128)

)
```

and selected everything you'd like to select:

```
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
    (SELECT  ltrim(rtrim(m_table.m)) AS m,
             ltrim(rtrim(t_table.t)) AS t, 
             ltrim(rtrim(z_table.z)) AS z,
             ltrim(rtrim(m_table.o)) AS o
    FROM  m_table INNER JOIN
          t_table ON m_table.t = t_table.Id_t_table INNER JOIN
          z_table ON m_table.z = z_table.Id_z_table
```

you finally put the cherry on the top... or rather cherry at the bottom of the function inside WHERE section:

```
WHERE (m_table.m = CASE WHEN @m_par IS NULL THEN
       m_table.m WHEN @m_par = '' THEN m_table.m END
       OR CHARINDEX(cast(@m_par AS nvarchar (30)),
       cast(m_table.m as nvarchar(30))) > 0)

       AND (t_table.t = CASE WHEN @t_par IS NULL THEN
       t_table.t WHEN @t_par = '' THEN t_table.t END
       OR CHARINDEX(cast(@t_par AS nvarchar (30)),
       cast(t_table.t as nvarchar(30))) > 0)

       AND (z_table.z = CASE WHEN @z_par IS NULL THEN
       z_table.z WHEN @z_par = '' THEN z_table.z END
       OR CHARINDEX(cast(@z_par AS nvarchar (30)),
       cast(z_table.z as nvarchar(30))) > 0)

       AND (m_table.o = CASE WHEN @o_par IS NULL THEN
       m_table.o WHEN @o_par = '' THEN m_table.o END
       OR CHARINDEX(cast(@o_par AS nvarchar (128)),
       cast(m_table.o as nvarchar(128))) > 0)
```

that should do the trick of filtering three tables joined in one query(function) with the output of four columns filtered by single letters or strings… also nulls and empty spaces.
        )